# embedding custom holidays into Facebook Prophet model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am trying to create my own holiday season and then plugging it to my Facebook prophet model, Does anyone know how I could implement that? So my data is basically the usage of e-resources by students at a University's library, and there is a seasonal trend from late May to mid-September where usage drops sharply, so I am trying to feed those dates as holidays into the model? any suggestions? I already added a dataframe of holidays into my model, which is for the country of England.

[image: image 1]